# The non-nullable variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make the user writing his birth to calculate the age in Flutter. But IDK why it is an error.

```
import 'dart:io';

class AgeCalculator {
  static int age;
  AgeCalculator(int p) {
    print('Enter your birth year: ');
    int birthYear = p;
    age = DateTime.now().year - birthYear;
    print('your age is $age');
  }
}
```

---

```
int str = 0;
```

---

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      AgeCalculator(int.parse(myController.text));
      str = AgeCalculator.age;
    });
  },
),
```

Comment: Can you include the error message

Answer (score 0):

Why is that a class? That needs to be a method:

```
int calculateAge(int birthYear) {
  return DateTime.now().year - birthYear;
}
```

And later using it like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      str = calculateAge(int.parse(myController.text));
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

While we are using null-safety, you need to

- assign value,   `static  int age = 0;`
- or using `late` to promise will assign value before read time. `static late  int age;`
- or make it nullable with `?` and do a null check while it. `static int? age;`

I prefer making nullable data.

Find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is this line:

```
  static int age;
```

You should be using the **later version of dart/flutter**. As you are declaring age non-nullable you *either* need to **define it as nullable** like that:

```
  static int? age;
```

or **give it some initial value** like:

```
  static int age = 0;
```

The other way is making it **late** variable. But **it has some danger**. If you try to make some action on it without giving value, you get error **in runtime**:

```
static late int age;
```